# Eclipse signals me an error in this POM, even after cleaning the project and validating it in XML

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I was getting an error because I mistakenly misplaced a dependency outside the dependencies tag. I corrected it, cleaned, updated, built, but I still have the error. What is wrong with my POM?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>it.polimi.ingsw</groupId>
<artifactId>cg_43</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>cg_43</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>  
<build>
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The Error that I'm getting is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":description, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement}' is expected.
```

Comment: This POM is fine. Make sure you clean the project in Eclipse "Project > Clean" and update the Maven project "right click > Maven > Update project"

Comment: I did that. but it's still there. I'll try restarting eclipse now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the project and importing it again made the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>it.polimi.ingsw</groupId>
<artifactId>cg_43</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging> replace with   <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.